# Multiple devices connected error in Robotframework

Tags: android, robotframework, android-uiautomator

I am using Robot Framework with UI-Automator for automating Native Android application.
In my current instance I have connected two devices to my PC- one for my general testing work and in the second device, I am running Automation. I have given serial of the device while running the test cases.

But I am getting following error in the console:

```
EnvironmentError: Multiple devices attached but default android serial not set
```

can somebody help me what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is on the documentation for the `Set Serial` keyword, on [uiautomatorlibrary.html](https://github.com/ming060/robotframework-uiautomatorlibrary/blob/master/doc/uiautomatorlibrary.html), below:

> `Set Serial    android_serial`
>
> Specify given android_serial device to perform test.
>
> You do not have to specify the device when there is only one device connects to the computer.
>
> When you need to use *multiple devices*, **do not use this keyword to switch between devices** in test execution.
>
> Using different library name when importing this library according to http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.8.5.
>
> | Setting |..Value.| .....  Value  ..... | . Value . |
> | Library | Mobile | WITH NAME | Mobile1 |
> | Library | Mobile | WITH NAME | Mobile1 |
>
> And set the serial to each library.
> | .... Test Case .... | ........ Action ........ | ..... Argument ..... |
> | Multiple Devices | Mobile1.Set Serial | device_1's serial |
> | .......................... | Mobile2.Set Serial | device_2's serial |