# How to execute a single test case in multiple devices using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am using RIDE tool (version: 1.5.2.1 running on python 2.7.6) using UIAUTOMATOR library. I have connected two android devices to my system and wanted to automate bluetooth pairing functionality between them.I have used 'Set Serial' keyword in my script but its showing error.

Could you please give me an example for using 'Set Serial' keyword or suggest me any other options available to achieve it.

What does this 'Set Serial' actually mean?

Comment: Ma i see your example code ?

Comment: Hope this one is can help you 


  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859752/multiple-devices-connected-error-in-robotframework

Comment: Below is sample code
*** Settings ***
Library           uiautomatorlibrary    WITH NAME    td
Library           uiautomatorlibrary    WITH NAME    ap
*** Test Cases *** Connecting multiple device
    td.Set Serial    device_1's serial
    ap.Set Serial    device_2's serial
    ###    Switching ON the bluetooth of test device (td)
    td.Click    text=Settings
    td.click    text=Bluetooth
    td.Swipe Right    10    text=OFF
    ###    Switching ON the bluetooth of android phone(ap)
    ap.Click    text=Settings
    ap.click    text=Bluetooth
    ap.Swipe Right    10    text=OFF

Comment: "Set Serial    android_serial" - My doubt is that what value should be given for 'android_serial'. Is it the phone's serial number?

Comment: Please don't post code in the comment section because it is impossible to read. You can [edit]  your question to add more detail.